# How can I set the time that Windows 7 changes the background in the background slideshow?

Tags: windows-7, desktop-customization

I've set up my Windows 7 background slideshow with a few choice wallpapers, and set it to cycle daily, nothing excessive - glad to see this feature built into Windows now.
My problem is that the change happens at 3 in the afternoon, the time when I originally set up the background. I'd like it to switch at night, so I can come in to work each day to a fresh look.

Is there a registry entry I can edit to manually set that switch time? Waiting until midnight to set it doesn't count.

Comment: if you don't want to wait until midnight, set the system time to 11:59 PM, wait EXACTLY ONE MINUTE, set your wallpaper, then set the time back to normal :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this is by design... [Link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproui/thread/13539844-dcab-4810-8bd3-54ab1663e37a) (a bit confused - looks like it does it on 30 seconds, but not 10 :S )

Anyway, what you can do is manually select the next one when you first come  in to work in the morning, then every day, the timer should be reset to do it at that time... if you set it to rotate at one day intervals.

Comment: Ah, but what happens when I change the settings, like adding one to the rotation? It'll reset the timer, right?  That time has got to be stored somewhere that can be edited...

Answer (score 0):

In windows 7, you cannot set a specific time, but you are allowed to set a duration to switch the desktop slide show. So if you want to see a new picture next morning, set the value data to be 86400000(24h) before 9 am.